# SQL How to select data like hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: 1]

I have data like this but I need to show data if user = 'L001' then show only data of row 1,3,4
and if user = 'L002' then show only data of row 2 & 5,
how to create a select query? (with no declare variable)

[image: This is result what I need if user = 'L001']
[image: This is result what I need if user = 'L002']

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: OK I'm sorry for this. I never post a question before. this is my first time. I will remember it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by **with no declare variable** but, in my opinion, you can use recursive CTE to create a hierarchy. Everything depends on the complexity of your data because your example is too short and you can use simple `union` for select what you need. Anyway, this is just one of many examples how to organaze it.

```
with rec as(
            select e.*,[USER] as Hierarchy from Employee e 
            where [USER] like 'L%'
            union all
            select e.*, ee.[USER] as Hierarchy from Employee e
            inner join rec ee on ee.SUB = e.MAIN
)
select MAIN,SUB,[USER] from rec where Hierarchy = 'L001'
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for an idea and I'm sorry if this make you a bit confusion.